# glm returning nan on simple translate

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

I'm tinkering with OpenGL using glfw, glad, and glm. In one of the tutorials I'm using, they demonstrate some simple usage of glm as so:

```
glm::vec4 vec(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glm::mat4 trans;
trans = glm::translate(trans, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
vec = trans * vec;
std::cout << vec.x << vec.y << vec.z << std::endl;
```

When I compile and run this code, I get trash values (usually NAN). The tutorial specifically noted that instantiating

```
glm::mat4 trans;
```

would by default create an identity matrix for the varialbe "trans". I'm thinking that perhaps this is the issue, though I have verified that glm does do this by default.

In case it would be helpful, you can find the entire source file [here](https://github.com/assemblyDruid/openGL-practice/blob/master/glmIntro.cpp) on line 308. I greatly appreciate your time!

Comment: Thanks Rabbid76. I just found out that glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f); is a more verbose way of doing what you've just shown. I was in the process of answering this question myself when you posted this. I can't accept an answer I posted for at least 2 days, so if you want to post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to initialize the matrix variable `glm::mat4 trans`.

The [glm API documentation](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00157.html#ga089315d5a0c20ac6eaa17a854bbd2e81) refers to [The OpenGL Shading Language specification 4.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.20.pdf).

> **5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors**
>
> If there is a single scalar parameter to a vector constructor, it is used to initialize all components of the constructed vector to that scalar’s value. **If there is a single scalar parameter to a matrix constructor, it is used to initialize all the components on the matrix’s diagonal, with the remaining components initialized to 0.0.**

This means, that an identity matrix can be initialized by the single parameter 1.0: `glm::mat4(1.0f)`.

Change your code somehow like this:

```
glm::mat4 trans(1.0f);
```

See also [OpenGL Mathematics (GLM); 2. Vector and Matrix Constructors](http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk3/Math/GLM/GLM.html#W01_0020_vector_and_matrix_con)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: though the tutorial and other sources said that glm would automatically instantiate an identity vector for

```
glm::mat4 trans;
```

it did not. Looking at a different tutorial, it seems that you can do so explicitly with

```
glm::mat4 trans = glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

And this solved the problem!

Comment: yeah, that's a weird behaviour, I was just dealing with the same nasty bug. `glm::mat4 m` supposed to automatically be initialized to identity matrix but it didn't. Maybe it's a version thing...